# Как уменьшить вес картинки с библиотекой Glide?

Tags: android, imageview, glide

Вставляю в свое приложение картинку из интернета при помощи библиотеки `Glide`. Картинка большого разрешения и весит многовато, при отображении ее в `ImageView` занимает слишком много оперативки. Есть у библиотеки такой метод как `sizeMultiplier()`, вот только я не понимаю как он работает и поможет ли мне. Подскажете, пожалуйста, с решением моей проблемы советом каким-нибудь.